# Swift Firebase returning empty array

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting an empty array back from firestore. Specifically from the sub model "Coor" inside of "EventModel".

Data Model:

```
struct EventModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var isLive: Bool
    var coors: [Coor]
    var eventCenterCoor: [Double]
    var hostTitle: String
    var eventName: String
    var eventDescription: String
    var isEventPrivate: Bool
    var eventGuestsJoined: [String]
    var eventEndDate: String
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case isLive
        case coors
        case eventCenterCoor
        case hostTitle
        case eventName
        case eventDescription
        case isEventPrivate
        case eventGuestsJoined
        case eventEndDate
    }
}

struct Coor: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var coorDoubles: [Double]
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case coorDoubles
    }
}
```

Firestore request:

```
    public func getEventData(completion: @escaping (_ eventModel: [EventModel]) -> Void) {
        var eventRef: [EventModel] = []
        self.isLoading = true
        self.loadingMess = "Finding events.."
        self.eventsDataCollection.whereField("isLive", isEqualTo: true)
            .getDocuments { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, error == nil {
                for doc in document.documents {
                    let data = doc.data()
                    let id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
                    let isLive = data["isLive"] as? Bool ?? false
                    let coors = data["coors"] as? [Coor] ?? []
                    let eventCenterCoor = data["eventCenterCoor"] as? [Double] ?? []
                    let hostTitle = data["hostTitle"] as? String ?? ""
                    let eventName = data["eventName"] as? String ?? ""
                    let eventDescription = data["eventDescription"] as? String ?? ""
                    let isEventPrivate = data["isEventPrivate"] as? Bool ?? false
                    let eventGuestsJoined = data["eventGuestsJoined"] as? [String] ?? []
                    let eventEndDate = data["eventEndDate"] as? String ?? ""
                    
                    eventRef.append(EventModel(id: id, isLive: isLive, coors: coors, eventCenterCoor: eventCenterCoor, hostTitle: hostTitle, eventName: eventName, eventDescription: eventDescription, isEventPrivate: isEventPrivate, eventGuestsJoined: eventGuestsJoined, eventEndDate: eventEndDate))
                }
                
                completion(eventRef)
            } else if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "Error getting events where 'isLive' == true")
                self.isLoading = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the firestore data:

[image]

Printing "coors" returns an empty array. The empty array is because  this line:

```
let coors = data["coors"] as? [Coor] ?? []
```

is defaulting to the empty array. This must mean the data type of [Coor] is incorrect?

Comment: Your Coor type has a property called coor that should be called coorDouble to match your data.

Comment: @jnpdx true, although does not matter if I cant even get the data in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are decoding an array called `coorsDouble` with this line:

```
let coorsDouble = data["coorsDouble"] as? [Coor] ?? []
```

If you look at your data structure, each element is made up of this structure:

```
{ coolDouble: [Double] }
```

But, in your `Coor` model, you have this structure:

```
struct Coor: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var coor: [Double]
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case coor
    }
}
```

In order to decode the `Coor`, you'd need its structure to match. So, change it to:

```
struct Coor: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var coorDouble: [Double]
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case coorDouble
    }
}
```

Next, `CodingKeys` only take effect when using `Codable`. Right now, you're just trying to cast a dictionary value (of type `Any`) to `Coor`, which isn't going to work. In general, I'd say you should use `Codable` with your *entire* structure, but if you wanted to avoid it for some reason, you'd need to do this:

```
//replacing let coorsDouble = data["coorsDouble"] as? [Coor] ?? []
let coorsDoubleArray = data["coorsDouble"] as? [[String:Any]] ?? []
let coorsDouble = coorsDoubleArray.compactMap { item in 
  guard let doublesArray = item["coorDoubles"] as? [Double] else {
    return nil
  } 
  return Coor(coorDoubles: doublesArray)
}
```

Comment: See edits, clarified the code and specific issue. It is not a naming issue, rather of why is my data defaulting.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Didn't realize you weren't actually using `Codable` at all to decode. Have you considered using the Firestore Swift function for automatic `Codable` decoding: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects

Comment: I use firestoreswift for setting the data, but I am getting multiple documents and I think you can only use firestoreswift for getting a single document

Comment: In theory I could get all the doc ids I want and call getdoc everytime and use firestoreswift but that seems more costly/less efficient.

Comment: Nothing would have to change about the number of firebase calls you make. The difference would be instead of `let data = doc.data()` and then all of your manual dictionary conversion, it would be `let model = try doc.data(as: EventModel.self)`

Comment: I get this error when doing that: "Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(QuerySnapshot?, Error?) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(QuerySnapshot?, Error?) -> Void'" Ill do some more research and post a new question if I cant figure it out.

Comment: You'd have to wrap the call in a `do/try/catch` block. Or, use `try?` instead of `try`

Comment: Do/catch did not work for some reason, that would of been my first guess. But try? works! I owe you a huge thank you, you have helped me out a lot today.